# Concat $filter not working in Odata Query

Tags: odata, kendo-datasource

**Hey pls help me in odata filter with concat function:
I am using following url:**
http://localhost:65314/ContractsWebServices/ContractsWebService/odata-contracts/VendorChangeOrderDetails/Default.GetConvertVendorChangeOrderIssues(contractId=1141)?$filter=concat(concat(IssueId, ' '), SplitIssueId) ne 422

**I am getting following error:**
"

The query specified in the URI is not valid. No function signature for the function with name 'concat' matches the specified arguments. The function signatures considered are: concat(Edm.String Nullable=true, Edm.String Nullable=true)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatype was mismatch in frontend code and WebApi. concat always works with string type as buddy said. in webapi, it was int  after changing to string, it got fix.

Answer (score 1):

concat takes a string, I suspect you are passing it a number in your issueid.

Comment: Though the signature of  concat() accepts only string but my column type is number. I have tried by passing the value as string in single quote.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are passing the value as a string?

Comment: In the context of your URI IssueId is the name of an entity field not a variable. The value of the entity field will be determined on a row by row basis in the server side controller